# Database management - looking for ideas

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, redis

I am doing my side project for a long time - it's a web-based online army battle simulator. In current stage i am getting huge data(of compressed armies), which i need to save in server. I can put them in SQL/noSQL/File (any of these or all of these), but i need it to be easy searchable and all the steps be made in 1~2 seconds.

I have a map, which has many rectangles - armies (not overlapping each other), approximately 100 at once. I need to get the list of only these rectangles, which are seen on my computer screen (screen is like a rectangle). So it would be - which rectangles overlap to given rectangle?

Data i have of every rectangle:

> x, width, y, height, rectangle_data (here is array of 1 to 10 millions other arrays).

First - i give data of my screen - width/height, x, y (x, y is not 0, because i can drag the map with mouse by changing the x,y).

Then i need to get the list of rectangles, which belong to my view. And download all data. And then i can watch the army battle animation which made of this data.

The real data i have:

```
// [x, width, y, height], [id, other_id], [huge_list_of_data]
[[[50,1,144,1],[1,3],[[92,134]]]] // one unit data
[[[92,1,134,1],[2,0],[[41,144]]]] // one unit data
[[[49,8,136,8],[1,2],[.. 64 arrays ..] // 64 units data
```

Approximately there are ~100 of these data rows, and all these 100 data rows belong to 1 animation frame. During the whole animation there are ~10000 animation frames. And there can be 100 animations per month.

So, i need to save all this data in server and have it easy searchable. So far my plan would be:

> Because the rectangle_data can be 10 millions array length, my plan is
>   to keep it in txt file.

> When i need the list of rectangles, i will provide current animation
>   frame, and by this frame i can search in database faster. But my plan is  to get 100 frames data at once, to reduce server IO and cache forward the army battle data for real 5 seconds.

> If i put only [x, width, y, height] values to redis DB, i could make
>   the keys in $redis like: animation_id.frame.x_width_y_height => example 11.151.50_1_144_1 , and the value points to rectangle_data storage location (txt File path and row_min ~ row_max, where is placed rectangle_data). But as you see, the 50_1_144_1 is not naturally searchable, i can parse this in server. Its not comfortable to search.

> Then i could get the list of all rectangles like
>   $redis.hkeys(animation_id, frame) and repeat it 100 times, for every frame. Or try something like find_in_batches if this works in this case. So i will get array of 50_1_144_1 - similar format sting's.

> With that information i would iterate the $redis string's array, which would be about 100*100 size and for every key get the value by asking $redis.hget(11, 151, 50_1_144_1) => hitting $redis DB 10.000 times. One of the values would be File name (for example 11.txt) and row numbers (for example 115~558). Then push this data to object like Object[11].push([115, 558]). Then for every object's key open the file, named as key, and fetch the data if this data-row is including to the array of rows range. Then make another object, and push this data to object[frame]. Then via AJAX send this massive object to frontend.

This is my plan so far. Was thinking about it few hours. And it sux. I am junior programmer and have no experience in such situations. But this is my side project, so i have a lot of time to decide.

Anyone have a better idea than my current one? I need something really better, how could i search trough that geolocational data faster. Acceptable any DB example, which could work easier in this situation. Im working with Ruby on Rails, and so far i know only postgres, mysql, redis, elasticseach DBs. So if it would be much better with some other mysterious DB, i will study it.